# Stop ffmpeg from creating multipart avi files

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert h264 avi files to Xvid format using FFMPEG. The video files are about 90min long. The code I am using is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libxvid -r 15 -an -vtag xvid -f avi output.avi
```

The problem is that the converted video files are Multipart files, as is stated by GSpot. This is problematic as I need to have singlepart files for the video analyses I am doing. I can't find how to set FFMPEG to create singlepart files and I can't use any other software as I have written a script to automatically convert videos with FFMPEG using R.

Here is the output file (without including all lines about the converted frames ofcourse):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\eeg2user>ffmpeg -i "E:\input.AVI" -c:v libxvid -
r 15 -an -vtag xvid -f avi E:\output.AVI
ffmpeg version N-32355-g4f7dfe1, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep  6 2011 13:06:48 with gcc 4.6.1
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-memalign-hack --enable-
runtime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libo
pencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --
enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger
 --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil    51. 16. 0 / 51. 16. 0
  libavcodec   53. 13. 0 / 53. 13. 0
  libavformat  53. 11. 0 / 53. 11. 0
  libavdevice  53.  3. 0 / 53.  3. 0
  libavfilter   2. 39. 0 /  2. 39. 0
  libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
Input #0, avi, from 'E:\input.AVI':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2012-12-01
    ICRT            : 15:50:14
    comment         :
  Duration: 01:11:14.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4136 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Main) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR
1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: aac ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 12
8 kb/s
[buffer @ 0204A080] w:1280 h:720 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:1/1 sws_param:
Output #0, avi, to 'E:\output.AVI':
  Metadata:
    ICRD            : 2012-12-01
    ICRT            : 15:50:14
    ICMT            :
    ISFT            : Lavf53.11.0
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4 (xvid / 0x64697678), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DA
R 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 15 tbn, 15 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0 (h264 -> libxvid)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    8 fps=  0 q=13.0 size=      54kB time=00:00:00.53 bitrate= 828.7kbits/
frame=   16 fps= 15 q=17.0 size=      90kB time=00:00:01.06 bitrate= 690.9kbits/
frame=   22 fps= 13 q=17.0 size=     103kB time=00:00:01.46 bitrate= 573.0kbits/
frame=   28 fps= 13 q=19.0 size=     129kB time=00:00:01.86 bitrate= 566.0kbits/
frame=   36 fps= 14 q=16.0 size=     138kB time=00:00:02.40 bitrate= 472.3kbits/
frame=   37 fps=  8 q=15.0 size=     156kB time=00:00:02.46 bitrate= 517.5kbits/
frame=   37 fps=  7 q=15.0 size=     156kB time=00:00:02.46 bitrate= 517.5kbits/
frame=   45 fps=  7 q=19.0 size=     174kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate= 475.5kbits/
s dup=0 drop=42
```

Comment: Please post the complete ffmpeg terminal output

Comment: Any ideas? It seems to happen when the created files go above 1.00gb

Comment: I have to admit, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'Multipart files' - do you mean that ffmpeg is splitting the output into multiple files? Or something else? The only thing I can think of is to try a different, more modern container (like mkv), but I don't think that would be a very satisfactory answer.

Comment: Also, if you can, please post the *full* terminal output; even the last few lines might give a clue as to what is going on (since I see nothing unusual in what's up there right now).

Comment: Thanks evilsoup. GSpot shows the avi file is actually a file that consists of two parts, called a 'multipart' avi. I'll add the whole output tomorrow as I have to rerun the converting..